# MySQL select query with between for second character having range of numbers from 0 to 9

Tags: mysql

I would like to select data from a table having first character as `*` and second character having numbers from 0 to 9

I using this code which is working and giving strings like `*0123456*` `*34567*` etc.:

```
SELECT * FROM `MyTable` WHERE SUBSTRING(MyColumn,1,1) = "*" AND    
(SUBSTRING(MyColumn,2,1) ="0" OR SUBSTRING(MyColumn,2,1) BETWEEN 1 AND 10) ;
```

But when I change the query to shorten it like this, it is giving strings having alphabets which I do not want

```
SELECT * FROM `MyTable` WHERE SUBSTRING(MyColumn,1,1) = "*" AND 
(SUBSTRING(MyColumn,2,1) BETWEEN 0 AND 10) ;
```

Why the 0 is not working with between in this query as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing this problem because MySQL will attempt to cast the non-numeric character to an integer before comparing it to 0 and 10. Due to MySQL's casting rules, non-numeric strings are always considered equal to zero, so the condition `BETWEEN 0 AND 10` is true.

```
-- The second character 'B' is equal to 0 after casting
> SELECT SUBSTRING('*BC', 2, 1) = 0;
+----------------------------+
| SUBSTRING('ABC', 2, 1) = 0 |
+----------------------------+
|                          1 |
+----------------------------+
```

Since you are matching a specific pattern, I would recommend doing this with a `REGEXP` match instead of chopping it up into substrings.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `MyTable` 
WHERE MyColumn REGEXP '(^\\*[0-9])'
```

Examples:

```
> SELECT '*123' REGEXP '^\\*[0-9]';
+---------------------------+
| '*123' REGEXP '^\\*[0-9]' |
+---------------------------+
|                         1 |
+---------------------------+

 > SELECT '*A23' REGEXP '^\\*[0-9]';
+---------------------------+
| '*A23' REGEXP '^\\*[0-9]' |
+---------------------------+
|                         0 |
+---------------------------+
```

The pattern match here breaks down to:

- `^` start of the string
- `\\*` match a literal `'*'`, requiring an escaping backslash
- `[0-9]` followed by a digit.

It is possible to use your method and avoid the casting if you use quoted strings in the `BETWEEN` as in `(SUBSTRING(msgbody,2,1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9')`

```
> SELECT SUBSTRING('*BC', 2, 1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9';
+--------------------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING('*BC', 2, 1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9' |
+--------------------------------------------+
|                                          0 |
+--------------------------------------------+

 > SELECT SUBSTRING('*99', 2, 1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9';
+--------------------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING('*99', 2, 1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9' |
+--------------------------------------------+
|                                          1 |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

But I prefer the `REGEXP` method because it expresses the whole pattern you wish to match as one condition. I find it much easier to read because the character positions are built into the expression, rather than needing to decode them from `substring()`. In either of these options, I expect MySQL will not utilize an index.

Comment: Thanks
Both methods work. Why do you prefer the `REGEXP` method ?

And where can I find MySQL`s casting rules ?

Comment: Your REGEXP code gives an error of replicate operator - operand.`'repetition-operator operand invalid'` So I put the code in brackets and is now working . Example - MyColumn REGEXP '(^\\\*[0-9])|(^\\\*.[0-9])' for choosing entries with first character as * and second or third character as a number. Please make correction in your answer and I will mark your answer as the right answer

Comment: @user20152015 I tested in 5.6 and had no such errors with my original pattern. The repetition-operator error would be due to a `|` you added, and yes in that case it would require `()`.

Comment: @user20152015 If you want to do the second or third as a digit, you don't need the `|` alternation because the `.` matches zero or one character. It can just be `REGEXP '^\\*.[0-9]'` including the `.` in the second position and eliminate the `|` and `()`. That will match either the second or third as a digit.

Comment: @ Michael, The REGEXP method does not use indexing while the substring method uses indexes. So, the regexp method gives false positives while the substring method does not. So, I prefer the substring method in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You're over-complicating things. In this specific case, if you say

> would like to select data from a table having first character as * and second character having numbers from 0 to 9

then you want everything from '*0...' to '*9....'.

So you want,

```
WHERE MyColumn >= '*0' AND SUBSTR(MyColumn, 1, 2) <= '*9';
```

The query would be more efficient if you knew that no value of MyColumn will ever exceed, say, "*9ZZZZZZZZ". Then you would ask

```
WHERE MyColumn >= '*0' AND MyColumn <= '*9ZZZZZZZZ'
```

or since usually 9 is followed lexicographically by ':', and you don't want it,

```
WHERE MyColumn >= '*0' AND MyColumn <= '*:'
```

which allows better use of an index on MyColumn.